# need sql query for this

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a mysql query for below:

**Currently iam doing individual queries as below:**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `myTable` WHERE `NAME` LIKE '%TYPE1%'; 
SELECT count(*) FROM `myTable` WHERE `NAME` LIKE '%TYPE2%';
SELECT count(*) FROM `myTable` WHERE `NAME` LIKE '%TYPE3%';
```

**But I need output as below:**

```
TYPEOF|COUNT(*)
===============
TYPE1|50
TYPE2|70
TYPE3|90
TYPE4|80
```

Comment: What are putting into `TYPEOF` column? `?  What is its logic?

Comment: @MikeB I need query in Mysql..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
case when `NAME` like '%TYPE1%' then 'TYPE1'
when `NAME` like '%TYPE2% then 'TYPE2'
...end as TYPEOF,
count (*)
from
`myTable`
group by
case when `NAME` like '%TYPE1%' then 'TYPE1'
when `NAME` like '%TYPE2% then 'TYPE2'
...end
```

Or, am I making this too complex?  Do you want all of the values in your NAME column?  If so, then:

```
select
`NAME`,
count (*)
from
`myTable`
group by `NAME`
```

Comment: hey, thanks first, actualy iam getting some syntax errror while trying to execute in mysql.. BTW, is this Mysql query?

Comment: I just threw it together.  Here's  a SQLFIddle that works:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a542d/10